# How to add php content or variable inside javascript alert box?! javascript, php, alertbox

Tags: php, javascript

How can i add php content or php variable inside Java-script alert box?!
I tried to make it work few ways but it is only popping up a blank box rather than the contents of php variable.

Here is the code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#a").blur(function() {           
            <?php $b = $_POST['a'];

            if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_travel set fld_a='".$_POST[$b]."' where fld_id = '".$_POST["id"]."' ") or die(mysql_error());
            } ?>

                alert (<?php $b ?>);
           });
    });
</script>
```

Thank You for your Help :)

Comment: `alert(<?php print($b); ?>);` will do

Comment: Thanks shankar..it works very well :)

Comment: Cool.Yw. Happy Coding !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a PHP variable to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148772/passing-a-php-variable-to-javascript)

Comment: @dianuj: well i guess it is, but i tried to search the question for duplicate entry before posting the question!!

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this

```
alert (<?php $b ?>);
```

to this

```
alert ('<?php echo $b; ?>');
```

You need to output the value of `$b` and add quotes inside the alert.

**About PHP - [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)**

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer totally missed using echo before $b. BTW need to put double quotes too  alert ("<?php echo $b; ?>");

Comment: I would love to but i cant do that due to very less reputation...!! If you don't mind please rate my question i need to have 15points..Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need low reputation to accept answer, just to upvote. You get also +2 when you accept. :)

Comment: oh is it...!! please let me know from where can i accept the answer...as i am a noob here ;) Thanks for an upvote..appreciate it :)

Comment: @Pooja, under the score of the answer  were you can upvote and downvote there is a check mark, press there in the answer you want to accept and you get +2 reputation. You have some other old questions you asked were you can do that also :)

Comment: @Pooja, exactly! if you do that on your other questions you will get more reputation also

Comment: oh yes i found it! Thanks for informing about that...accepted your answer ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
alert ('<?php echo $b ?>');
```

Answer (score 2):

I use it like this

```
$text="Example PHP Variable Message";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$text.'")</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
<script>
  alert("</script><?php $r=5;echo $r;?> <script>")
</script>
```

you have to script off on when php start

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
alert ("<?php echo $b; ?>");
```