# Pass value from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello Im trying to pass value stored in php to javascript code.

I try to pass the value in `$_SESSION[user]`

If I have this script in my header:

```
<script>

var user = ? //How to pass the value?

</script>
```

In my buttons I do something like this:

```
onclick="foo('<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION[user];?>')
```

But how do I pass it without the user click?

Thanks for helping

**EDIT**

My JS function located in other file and I reference them by this code in my header:

```
<script src="class_functions"></script>
```

How do I pass the same parameter to the other file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a PHP variable to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148772/passing-a-php-variable-to-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have added an additional factor to your question, it is a little bit more interesting. If you need to set a variable when the functions that use this variable are located in a different file, then you need to decide the scope of the variable you are passing.  There are several options; I will just list two:

1. Global scope. That is, the variable will be "known" to the other functions because of where it it located. You want to be careful of this, but if that's your approach you can use any of the answers given, e.g.

   ```
   <script>
   var x = '<?= $_SESSION["user"];>';
   </script>
   ```
2. Local scope. Now you will need to include a function in `class_functions` that sets the variable. You might end up with something like

   ```
   <script>
     set_user('<?= $_SESSION["user"];>');
   </script>
   ```

Where the `set_user()` function is defined in your other file, and ensures that the variable is available to the other functions with the correct scope.

I would prefer using method 2 - it is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. I used the set_user :)

Answer (score 5):

Just echo the PHP value out like you would any content:

```
<script>
    var user = '<?php echo $_SESSION[user]; ?>';
</script>
```

JavaScript is just client-side code like HTML is.

Comment: Or the even shorter `  var user = '<?= $_SESSION[user]; ?>';`

Comment: Yep. Be careful though. Newbies will tell you to never use short tags!

Comment: Its working thanks. But now i have another problem please see my edit, thanks.

Comment: Would be a good idea to check for the session index to be set though.

Comment: @geekynotsilly That would only be necessary if this was not behind some sort of login. If you've authenticated the user then you can be sure that information exists.

Comment: Guess *user* normally should be quoted. (PHP-code).

Answer (score 4):

If you're PHP script is rendering the page, I would go with the script tag approach.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var user = '<?php echo $_SESSION["user"]; ?>';
   </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is better:

```
<script>
    var user = '<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION["user"]); ?>';
</script>
```

Because if there are quotes $_SESSION['user'], you will get an error.
For example if you have:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = "something with 'quotes'";
```

the js would like so:

```
var user = 'something with 'quotes'';
```

Which is incorrect.

Comment: You shouldn't use addslashes(). You should use htmlentities().

Comment: You should avoid short_open tags for your example because it is configuration depended if it works or not. And I agree use htmlenitites()

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Jquery ,if you want it to happen automatically.

just Use the following code inside your  tags

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var user= <? echo $_SESSION['user']?>;
    //Code Goes here......

});
```

Hope that solves Your Problem

**Note:This can be one of the many possible solutions**

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. If one include jQuery only to add an onload event, for which one do not need jQuery, one have to seriously rethink the approach.

Comment: I know jquery is JAVASCRIPT, the question was about to pass PHP value to JavaScript without buttons.......and this can be one of the ways to pass the data

Comment: You do not need to wait for DOM to set a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Unless *user* is a number or some literal like *false* or *null* etc., it will also break the script.

Comment: You can check for null or other conditions using if statement

Comment: So *user* should be *null*, *false* or the like. (Or a possible earlier global variable)? Hint: What if `$_SESSION['user']` is *John Wayne*? What if it is *usr123* and there is no global variable *usr123*?